# a surjective function is closed iff it maps Borel sets to Borel sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ surjective. Why is $f$ closed if and only if the image of any Borel set is a Borel set? For one direction, it would clearly be sufficient to prove that, if $f$ is closed, the image of any open set is Borel, but I don't know how to proceed from there. For the other direction, I don't have any idea how to proceed.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to include surjectivity of $f$ as a condition. I had the impression that this is claimed on https://eudml.org/doc/221126, page 91, example 1.12 (i). The definition of an inverse image of a multifunction $F$, definition 1.11, seems to reduce to the image of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if $F:=f^{-1}$ is the multifunction that maps $y\in Y$ to the preimage of $y$ under $f$. So upper continuity of $f^{-1}$, as defined there, seems to be equivalent to the statement that $f$ maps Borel sets to Borel sets.

Comment: I meant upper semi-continuity as defined in 1.11 again... sorry for the many mistakes.

Comment: In my answer change f (0) to 0 and consider the imagre of  the set of natural numbers.

Comment: It seems to me that one should consider the image of $\mathbb{N}^+$. The image of $\mathbb{N}$ (which, if I am not mistaken, is $C:=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$) seems to be closed to me; I don't see any sequence in $C$ whose limit point is not in $C$ (and, in fact, it seems to me that $C$ can be represented as the complement of the union of $]-\infty,0[$, $]1,\infty[$ and $]1/(i+1),1/i[$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}^+$). But do you have an idea what to make of my reference?

Comment: I looked again into the paper, and it all makes sense now. I apparently mixed up their notation for closed and Borel measurable sets last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th statement is blatantly false. Let $f(x)=1/x$ if $x \neq 0$ and 1 if $x=0$. Then $f$ maps Borel sets to Borel sets but $f$ is not closed.

Comment: Sorry, but what would be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose image is not closed under $f$? Intervals (or finite unions of intervals) don't seem to be enough for me.

Comment: of course $\mathbb{R}$... Thank you for the counterexample, but as I wrote, my original statement was in fact wrong.